# Every time I reboot Ubuntu 20.04, the the opposite NIC becomes active and the names swap

Tags: networking, server, swap, nic

This is driving me crazy. Every time I reboot my 2 NIC server, The names of the two interfaces swap with each other but obviously the MAC addresses stay the same. I can get a network connection but I have to unplug the cable and plug it into the other NIC. The other NIC is just inactive. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: this sounds like an old problem that doesn't exist much these days... what are you using to configure your network? What are your interface names? Are you trying to force a interface to have a specific name somewhere else in a configuration?

Comment: Forgive me if I answer any of these questions incorrectly, my linux knowledge is basic at best, but my understanding is that I am using Network manager to configure my network. I'm not trying to do that intentionally, as far as I know. I just want one specific interface to always come up so the server always gets the same IP address.  My interface names are eth0 and eno1.

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using? You should include those things in your questions. Based on your response, I am wondering how you got a kernel name (eth0) and a predictable name(eno1) both configured? I had the same problem when I wanted to force the old kernel names because i didnt like the predictable name. But the truth is, that problem is fixed by the predictable name scheme. Can you edit to your question, adding lines in **/etc/default/grub** containing GRUB_CMDLINE and contents of **/etc/udev/rules.d/-persistent-net.rules**. Did you do the original configuration for this server?